# converting double fat arrow to standard function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

While reading the following article: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-pure-function-d1c076bec976
and I got to the following piece of code:

```
const highpass = (cutoff, value) => value >= cutoff;
```

Which outputs:

```
highpass(5, 123); // true
highpass(5, 5);   // true
highpass(5, 1);   // false
```

Since I'm not an expert on fat arrow function I tried to convert them into simple functions, but the second fat arrow and the result are confusing me, here's what I have so far:

```
function highpass(cutoff, value)
{
    return function(value)
    {
        return function(cutoff)
        {
            ????????
        }
    };
};
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `=>` is not the same as `>=`

Comment: I think youre missing that `>=` is not an arrow... ;) and i still dont get why this is a "fat arrow function", theyre really lightweight in my opinion... A " double arrow function" would be `highpass = a => b => a >= b` which would enable currying as: `highpass(5)(1)`

Comment: I only noticed it when you pointed it out, I'm so ashamed of my question now

Answer (score 2):

That is equivalent to

```js
const highpass = function(cutoff, value){
  return value >= cutoff;
}

console.log(highpass(2, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one arrow function at code at Question, `>=` is [Greater Than or Equal operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Greater_than_or_equal_operator)

```
function highpasss(value, cutoff) {return value >= cutoff}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "second" is a comparison, not a function

```
const highpass = (cutoff, value) => value >= cutoff;
```

translates to

```
const highpass = function(cutoff, value) {
    return value >= cutoff;
}
```